# Where are all the purple eridium totems?

Tags: borderlands-2

As mentioned in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/101717/what-is-this-purple-eridium-totem), I've been finding eridium totems while playing through Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt. By now I believe we've found 4 totems and dumped nearly 100 eridium into them, but there seem to be more to go.

Where are all the eridium totems located? Map(s) are ideal.

[image: Eridium totem]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This link contains maps to all of the Eridium Totems: 
http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Dexiduous_Eridium_Totem_Furnace

There's four of them, all in Hunter's Grotto. Image from http://orcz.com reproduced here:

[image]